# How to have an application moved to launcher in stripped-down Unity under Ubuntu

Tags: unity

I installed Ubuntu server and then the stripped down Unity desktop. I then installed terminator. I see terminator in the Software Center. I can also locate the .desktop file for this application and the content appear to be find  - I have not edited any of the lines there. I want to have this Terminator application in the launcher. How do I do this?  I am new to Unity and admittedly rusty with Ubuntu.

Yes, if I had the full blown Unity installed, its straight forward. As a server administrator, I think having a desktop is not recommended in the first place. However, I prefer to have the productivity in a desktop interface and therefore installed the stripped-down (--no-install-recommends option to apt-get) version of Unity. I want to have some applications seen in the launcher. With a full-blown Unity installed, this is, of course, simple. Please take the hold of this question.